# ACL in laravel 5.1 , delete post abilities on each post shown in user page

Tags: php, laravel, collections, acl, posts

I have an user page where I show all the posts by that user.
This page can be accessed by other users more or less like instagram.
Now the point is I want to show in every single post in that page a list for options available to the user who posted and not the other users.
I checked the documentation, all the examples are on pages that show one post (my.project/post/1) let's say, so obviously that is received through a get method and in the view you can add the `@can` method and define the `gate` in the controller that spits out the post to that page.
But what if I am sending all the posts to the page like this:

```
 public function index()
    {


        $user = Auth::user();

        $posts_with_comments = Post::with(['comments.author',

            'user' => function ($q) {

                $q->select('id', 'username');
            },

             'some_stuff'])->where('user_id', $user->id)->get()->reverse();


        return view('user.page')->with('posts',$posts_with_comments);



    }
```

I registered a policy like this:

```
class PostPolicy

{

    /**
     * @param User $user
     * @param Post $post
     * @return bool
     */
    public function deletePost(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;

    }
```

in AuthServiceProvider

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{


    protected $policies = [

        \App\Post::class => \App\Policies\PostPolicy::class


    ];


    /**
     * Register any application authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Gate  $gate
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(GateContract $gate)
    {
        parent::registerPolicies($gate);
    }
}
```

so how do I manage the `gate` stuff in the controller to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything in your controller regarding displaying this stuff. You can do it in the view. (You can go about this in other ways as well)

```
@foreach ($posts as $post)
    ...
    @can('deletePost', $post)
        ... only if the user is authorized ...
    @endcan
@endforeach
```

For the actions though in the controller you can use the `authorize` method if you would like.

```
public function delete($id)
{
    $post = Post::findOrFail($id);

    $this->authorize('deletePost', $post);

    ...
}
```

[Laravel 5.1 Docs - Authorization - Controller Authorization](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#controller-authorization)

Comment: well, it doesn't work, it returns: FatalErrorException in 7fddb6f740b983cdec1ab1c56806aeda line 20:
Class 'Gate' not found

Comment: does `config/app.php` in the `aliases` array have an entry for `'Gate' => .....` ?

Comment: I discovered not, however I followed the guide to upgrade to 5.1.11 and I still get the same error. I am using Laravel Framework version 5.1.28 (LTS)

Comment: so you added the alias for `Gate`?

Comment: yes, I added App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class, and 'Gate'      => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate::class, as per the guide, updated the user model and the base controller and run php artisan optimize... still no go.